# Selenium Java popup authentication "http://user:pass@xyz.com" does not work

Tags: java, http, selenium, authentication, popup

It doesn't show any of the fields as filled in nor does it try to fill them in. Do you know what other solutions I could use? Right now I am doing

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String user = "kek";
    String pass = "trekek";
    String url = "http://www."+ user + ":" + pass + "@xyz.org/auth.html";
    System.out.println(url);
    driver.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the URL with the username and password appears to be wrong. You have a www in front of the credentials, try changing it to something like:

```
String url = "http://"+ user + ":" + pass + "@www.xyz.org/auth.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't show any of the fields as filled in nor does it try to fill them in.

And neither should it!  When you use a URL like that, the HTTP specs say that the client sends the server a GET request with some credentials embedded in the URL.  What the server does with this depends on how you have implemented the server.

Now you could in theory implement your server to send back a login page with details prepopulated, but I wouldn't.

- Putting user details in a URL is insecure.  They will show up in server-side logs.
- It is **horribly insecure** if you use an HTTP URL, 'cos that means that the URL will be transmitted in the clear over the network.  It is easy for a hacker to snoop an unencrypted connection.
- This is not functionality that most users would normally use.  (Nor would we want them to; see above!)
- This is not the way that a sane person would want to implement (or use) a RESTful API.

---

Solutions?

- If you are implementing Selenium tests for an existing server, then you need to drive the server's login sequence the way it was designed to work.  Send the request that triggers the server to give you a login page.  Simulate filling in the fields and clicking "login".  Extract the session cookies from the response.
- If you control the server (i.e. you can change it), you could design an alternative web API for programmatic authentication; i.e. where your Selenium tests don't need to simulate the filling in and submission of a login form.  But PLEASE do it securely.  User names and passwords should only be transmitted over HTTPS.

Comment: Ok this makes some sense. So this is not super important to have 100% secure but lets say you want to test 2 username password combos: one if it works, another if it doesn't work, do I just use the URL for the first one and if it doesnt work, simulate filling them in using selenium? How do I test if it works and doesn't work?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  What is your real use-case here?  Is this for webscraping lots of different sites?

Comment: To be honest I'm just trying to mess with selenium for the first time to try to log onto this form and just see what works. Is selenium the best way to do this or can I send a request in another way?

Comment: Selenium is fine, but trying to use a URL with embedded credentials is unlikely to work.  (You can confirm this by trying to enter the URL with embedded credential into the URL type-in using your favorite web browser.)

Comment: Ok stephen what would you recommend instead? we're trying to log onto an authentication page my friend made

Comment: I recommend that you ask your friend.  Or reverse engineer what he has done.  Or get him to >>change<< it to make it easier.